# How to measure Johnson Noise precisely experimentally?

Tags: experimental-physics, electrical-resistance, noise

I want measure Johnson Noise across a resistor having certain over the certain range of frequency or bandwidth practically. I am starting from scratch, how can I build circuitry and instrumentation so that I will get more precise output values. Like theoretically we can calculate (for example, [Vn]^2 = 4RKT∆f ; Vn = 1.6mV for R=16kΩ, T=300K, ∆f=10kHz, K= Boltzmann constant ) but practically I am facing some problems with circuitry.

Comment: What kinds of instruments do you have available? Will you be measuring the resistor temperature? What circuitry is giving you problems?

Comment: Related question by same user : [Johnson Noise experimental measurement](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/503001). Also [Noise Fundamentals - Johnson Noise](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/503305).

Comment: @Gilbert Yes I'm measuring the surrounding temperature of resistor. I'm having problem in building circuitry of op-amp and it's gain, feedback resistors.

Comment: @learner probably you want to ask about the circuitry on the electrical engineering stack exchange.